# Why is Todo able to make recommendations to Principal Gakuganji for promoting Jujutsu sorcerers to Grade 1?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

During the final credits scene of the last episode of *Jujutsu Kaisen*, we see that Mei Mei and Todo Aoi are presenting their recommendations to Principal Gakuganji of Kyoto Jujutsu Tech, who is also head of the conservative, for promoting to Grade 1 sorcerers some of the students who participated in the recent Sister-School Goodwill Event.

As far as I can tell, it is implied that Mei Mei is a teacher at the Kyoto school, since during the Goodwill Event she was observing the students along with many other faculty. So, it makes sense that her recommendations for promotion are being concerned.

However, Todo Aoi is a third year student at Kyoto Jujutsu Tech who, in fact, participated in the Goodwill Event. So, why are his recommendations being considered? From the explanation in episode 15, it seems to be implied that it is the faculty that make recommendations for promotion; in particular, it is mentioned that they cannot recommend their own students.

So, why are Todo's recommendations for promotion to Grade 1 sorcerers being considered? Is it because, as Zenin Mai mentions in episode 8, Todo is himself a Grade 1 sorcerer, and Grade 1 sorcerers are also possibly allowed to make recommendations? Or, is there more to Todo than meets the eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about his rank allowing him to do so. Basically, the person giving the recommendation has to be ranked higher than you.

When it comes to being ranked to grade 1, they need to have recommendations from 2 or more sorcerers of that rank which Aoi Todo and Mei Mei are both Grade 1. The recommendation alone isn't enough to be promoted right away. The nominees still has to accompany sorcerer's of Grade 1 level (cannot be the person who nominated them) to multiple missions and exorcise a Grade 1 on their own.

Here's a link to reference:
https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Grade